# Performance Issues with Count(*) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, count, aggregate

I am having some performance issues with a query I am running in SQL Server 2008. I have the following query:

Query1:

```
 SELECT GroupID, COUNT(*) AS TotalRows FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Column1 FROM Table2 WHERE GroupID = @GroupID
    ) AS Table2
     ON Table2.Column1 = Table1.Column1 
WHERE CONTAINS(Table1.*, @Word) GROUP BY GroupID
```

Table1 contains about 500,000 rows. Table2 contains about 50,000, but will eventually contain millions. Playing around with the query, I found that re-writing the query as follows will reduce the execution time of the query to under 1 second.

Query 2:

```
SELECT GroupID FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Column1 FROM Table2 WHERE GroupID = @GroupID
    ) AS Table2 ON Table2.Column1 = Table1.Column1 
WHERE CONTAINS(Table1.*, @Word)
```

What I do not understand is it is a simple count query. If I execute the following query on Table 1, it returns in < 1 s:

Query 3:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Table1
```

This query returns around 500,000 as the result.

However, the Original query (Query 1) mentioned above only returns a count of 50,000 and takes 3s to execute even though simply removing the GROUP BY (Query 2) reduces the execution time to < 1s.

I do not believe this is an indexing issue as I already have indexes on the appropriate columns. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Does SQL Server have "explain plan"?

Comment: Yes, it does. In Management Studio, there's a button to click to view the query plan.

Comment: About the question: why are you doing a `SELECT Column1 FROM Table2 WHERE GroupID = @GroupID`, instead of just joining with Table2?

Comment: @PaulTomblin I have already reviewed the execution plan, and the funny thing is that the aggregate part of the plan has an extrmely small cost relative to the rest of the query.

Comment: @Diego, In the past I have experienced better results in complicated queries by creating sub tables like this.

Comment: @Chris I can't think of a situation where a subselect would work better than a simple join. I dealt with all sorts of complicated queries on huge databases, but I solved all performance issues with an analysis of the Execution Plan. I'm just trying to make sure there's a reason behind that choice, rather than a "coincidence".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing a simple `COUNT(*) FROM table` can do a much more efficient scan of the clustered index, since it doesn't have to care about any filtering, joining, grouping, etc. The queries that include full-text search predicates and mysterious subqueries have to do a lot more work. The count is not the most expensive part there - I bet they're still relatively slow if you leave the count out but leave the group by in, e.g.:

```
SELECT GroupID FROM Table1 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Column1 FROM Table2 WHERE GroupID = @GroupID
    ) AS Table2 ON Table2.Column1 = Table1.Column1 
WHERE CONTAINS(Table1.*, @Word)
GROUP BY GroupID;
```

Looking at the [provided actual execution plan](http://www.wperfumes.com/plan.zip) in [the free SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp)*, I see this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Which lead me to believe you should:

1. Update the statistics on both `Inventory` and `A001_Store_Inventory` so that the optimizer can get a better rowcount estimate (which could lead to a better plan shape).
2. Ensure that `Inventory.ItemNumber` and `A001_Store_Inventory.ItemNumber` are the same data type to avoid an implicit conversion.

(*) *disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*

Comment: Yes, that is still slow. Simply removing the Group By speeds it up significantly. Any idea why?

Comment: @ChrisTremblay probably because there isn't an index on GroupID to help with the grouping.

Comment: @ChrisTremblay I wouldn't want to see an image. I'd want to see the actual .sqlplan file, which you could post to any file-sharing service that doesn't require downloaders to log in.

Comment: You can dlownload the file from the following address: http://www.wperfumes.com/plan.zip

Comment: @ChrisTremblay I would start by updating the statistics for the A001_Store_Inventory table. I would also make sure that Inventory.ItemNumber and A001_Store_Inventory.ItemNumber are the same data type (seems one is NVARCHAR(15), the other is not).

Comment: I just made the change and I will test as soon as the CPU isn't maxed.

Comment: That appears to have made a considerable difference in the sub tree cost. It went from 8.x to 0.07. I didn't realize they were not the same data type. I am still waiting to test the execution until the CPU is not as busy. After updating the table, the CPU went crazy. I think it is updating the indexes. So far, looks like your anser will get a +1. If you want to respond with the answer, I can +1 it as soon as I test the execution and verify that it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the query plan to see what SQL Server is doing to retrieve the data you requested. Also, I think it would be better to rewrite your original query as follows:

```
SELECT
  Table1.GroupID  -- When you use JOINs, it's always better to specify Table (or Alias) names
  ,COUNT(Table1.GroupID) AS TotalRows
FROM
  Table1 
  INNER JOIN
  Table2 ON
    (Table2.Column1 = Table1.Column1) AND
    (Table2.GroupID = @GroupID)
WHERE
  CONTAINS(Table1.*, @Word)
GROUP BY
  Table1.GroupID
```

Also, keep in mind that a simple COUNT and a COUNT with a JOIN and GROUP BY are not the same thing. In one case, it's just a matter of going through an index and making a count, in the other there are other tables and grouping involved, which can be time consuming depending on several factors.

Comment: I just tested this query and I get the same result as in the OP with ~ 3s execution time. I have reviewed the execution plan, and the COMPUTE and AGGREGATE parts of the plan had the smallest operator costs of the entire query. That's what I don't understand.